# Laravel: Iterate through join collection

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent, iteration

I have a laravel DB collection which retrieves data using joins. As this:

```
public static function getAllClientData(){

return DB::table('clients')
    ->join('accounts', 'clients.id',  '=', 'accounts.client_id')
    ->join('addresses', 'clients.address_id',  '=', 'addresses.id')
    ->select('clients.*', 'accounts.*', 'addresses.*')
    ->get();
}
```

Now I want to get the values of the returned DB collection. However, the table accounts and clients contain both the column "comment". This column is not the same column and contains different values. How can I iterate through the returned DB collection and access/get the value of the specified column?

I have already tried this so far:

```
foreach($data as $item){
    echo $item->addresses.comment;
    echo $item->accounts.comment;
}
```

However, it is not working. How can I tell Laravel to get the value of the column comment from the table addresses and also next from the table accounts?

Comment: Try dumping the data to find out how the data is retrieved in php. `dd($data);`

Comment: Can't you set up Eloquent relationships?! You are using Laravel and not using its most powerful feature [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent).

Answer (score 0):

You could use eloquent way with eager load your relations

```
$clients = Client::with(['accounts','addresses'])->get();
```

When you loop through `$clients` on each iteration you will have a collection for related addresses and accounts for each client

```
class Client extends Model{

    public function accounts(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Accounts','client_id');
    }

}
```

Also your relation with addresses looks suspicious if a client has one address then its ok to have an address id in clients table, If a client has multiple addresses then addresses table should have a client_id as foreign key,

If client has one address

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Address', 'address_id');
}
```

If client has more than one address

```
public function addresses(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Address','client_id');
}
```

For you original query you need to assign them unique alias if 2 tables have same name for columns

```
DB::table('clients')
    ->join('accounts', 'clients.id',  '=', 'accounts.client_id')
    ->join('addresses', 'clients.address_id',  '=', 'addresses.id')
    ->select('clients.*', 'accounts.*', 'addresses.*', DB::raw('accounts.comments as account_comments'),DB::raw('addresses.comments as address_comments'))
    ->get();
```

Also its not a good idea to select all the columns from a joined query, select only columns that you really need